# How to Recover from Creating a Branch from the Wrong Branch Instead of Main

Tags: git

I find myself in the following scenario with Git every so often:

1. From the main branch, I create and checkout branch A
2. On branch A, I do some work, create some commits, etc., then push my changes
3. I need to do some unrelated work, so I create and checkout branch B
4. I create some more commits on branch B and push
5. I go to create a PR and... oops. I Created branch B from branch A, so suddenly I have all these irrelevant commits from branch A in my PR. I needed to create branch B from the main branch instead.

Just wondering what the best workflow is here. Sure, I can delete branch B, create it again and replicate my commits, but that seems tedious. A rebase is not an option, as I have already pushed to a remote repo. Maybe I can revert all the commits that were carried over from branch A to B? Maybe I should just create an alias that will checkout main before creating the branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplest solution: rebase onto**

`git rebase` has the onto mode to do exactly what you want:

```
git rebase --onto main A B
```

will take B off of A and rebase it onto main.

If you have B checked out when you run this, you don't need to specify it on that rebase command line.

**Cherry Pick option** You can also do it with a cherry pick operation.

Create a new branch off of the right place, cherry pick all the commits from B onto it, and then reset B to it afterwards.

```
git checkout main  # or where the branch should start from
git checkout -b B-new  # pick a new name, you'll need access to both B and B-new
git cherry-pick A..B  # cherry pick all commits on B not on A
```

Now `B-new` is the branch you wanted to create in the first place. You can just use the new name, or if you want to keep the name `B`, reset it to `B-new`:

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard B-new
```

And clean up, since you no longer need `B-new` now:

```
git branch -d B-new
```

But all that is doing exactly what the rebase onto did...

Comment: `will take B off of A and rebase it onto main` I was looking for that explaination for a very long time, thanks!